# WCF not returning service end point

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

I am trying to return a list of entities from my WCF data service. I am not using Entity Framework but rather pulling the data out of Neo4j and returning those asQueryeable . I get a 404 error if I run the code saying that the url could not be found for the ObjectEntitiesService.svc?

Here is my code:
The Object

```
[DataServiceKeyAttribute("Id")]
    public class ObjectEntity 
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EntityType { get; set; }
        public int Version { get; set; }
        public string DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Getting the data:

```
    public partial class ObjectEntityData
    {
        static List<ObjectEntity> objectEntityList;
        static ObjectEntityOperations objectEntityOps;
        static ObjectEntityData()
        {
            var foundEntities = objectEntityOps.GetAllObjectEntities();

            foreach (var graphNode in foundEntities)
            {
                var entityInformation = new ObjectEntity()
                {
                     Id = graphNode.Data.Id,
                     Name = graphNode.Data.Name,
                     DateTimeCreated = graphNode.Data.DateTimeCreated,
                     Version = graphNode.Data.Version,
                     Status = graphNode.Data.Status,
                     EntityType = graphNode.Data.EntityType
                };

                objectEntityList.Add(entityInformation);
            }
        }

        public IQueryable<ObjectEntity> Items
        {
            get { return objectEntityList.AsQueryable<ObjectEntity>(); }
        }
    }
```

Service Class

```
public class ObjectEntitiesService : DataService<ObjectEntityData>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Items", EntitySetRights.AllRead);

            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you see the ObjectEntitiesService.svc url in a browser? i.e. when you run via VS, if you go to: http://localhost/.../ObjectEntitiesService.svc do you see anything? The most likely reason is that the URL for your service reference is pointing to the wrong place...

Comment: No I cannot see it in the browser, If I run it in VS on localhost:XXX/ObjectEntitiesServices.svc it says 404 not found. Where can I check the URL service reference?

Comment: Simplest way would be to set the .svc as your startup item in the project, then run it, that should show you the location...